# How to save a file in pandas using if statement?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I would like to save the lines only if field 2 and field 3 doesn't match. For example in id "AAA" ,

```
id    field2    field3
AAA    SRE        SRE
AAA    FSD        FRE
AAA    TUE        TUE
ABA    SDE        SDE
AAA    FRT        QRE
AAA    HRE        HRE
ABA    EEE        EEE
ABA    URE        FRE
```

How to save to output file using if statement,

```
file = "/output.csv"
df.to_csv(file, sep="%", index=False)
```

Comment: `df[df['field2'] != df[field3]].to_csv(file, sep='%', index=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
In [121]: df[df['field2']!=df['field3']]
Out[121]: 
    id field2 field3
1  AAA    FSD    FRE
4  AAA    FRT    QRE
7  ABA    URE    FRE

In [122]: df[df['field2']!=df['field3']].to_csv(file, sep="%", index=False)

In [123]: df = df[df['field2']==df['field3']]

In [124]: df
Out[124]: 
    id field2 field3
0  AAA    SRE    SRE
2  AAA    TUE    TUE
3  ABA    SDE    SDE
5  AAA    HRE    HRE
6  ABA    EEE    EEE
```

Comment: also, how to remove the lines from the data df , if field 2 is not equal to field 3

Comment: @Iris `df = df[df['field2'] == df[field3]]`